# Adding "email" and "profile" scopes to https://code.google.com

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-console

Drive SDK API configuration still points to the old form at code.google.com, and it has a problem with the new "email" and "profile" scopes we need to add instead of the deprecated ones (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email). 
The problem is that the console doesn't allow this format: "email" / "profile" and fails with the error message:

```
An unexpected error has occurred. We're looking into it.
```

Does anyone have a workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

These scopes have been [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable) for a long time and not otherwise suggested to be used even though it says that these scopes will be maintained for backward compatibility. If you still haven't done so, I'd suggest you to migrate to the [profile](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#oauth2login) and [email](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#email) scopes.

Comment: It looks like you haven't read the entire message. We are trying to migrate to the new scopes (email and profile), but the console doesn't allow them.

Comment: Excuse me for that, I think I misunderstood the issue at the moment. Does this issue still exist?

Comment: Yes, the issue still exists even in the new console (at https://console.developers.google.com). What I see is the same error message when trying to save "email" and "profile" instead of the deprecated url-like scopes: http://i.imgur.com/GRNC8SS.png. The scopes I'm trying to save are the following: http://i.imgur.com/GW49P6S.png